# Is there a parser which will take in html as input and convert it into a stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, html-parsing, markup, css-parsing

I had this idea for a while and am wondering if such a thing exists,
Basically, I would like to see a parse which will take in some html such as:

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="giftcard-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And convert it into:

```
.page-content {

}

.page-content-wrapper {

}

.giftcard-content {

}
```

And off course, some bonus points if it can actually read inline styles and fill those in as well.

Anyone knows if such a thing exists?
If not, maybe I'll make one...

Answer (score 2):

Check out [primerCss](http://primercss.com/), this appears to be what you are looking for.